# Show that $\lvert \cos (1)\lvert $ + $\lvert \cos (2)\lvert $ + $\lvert \cos (3)\lvert \geq \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

Show that $\lvert \cos (1)\lvert $ + $\lvert \cos (2)\lvert $ + $\lvert \cos (3)\lvert \geq \frac{3}{2}$.

I've been trying to figure out an analytic way of showing this is true for a while now, but I can't seem to come up with anything. I have tried using things like the Triangle Inequality, and screwing around with the identity $\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$, but the bounds it seems to provide are too low. Any ideas/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I haven't thought about this at all, but have you tried Taylor series?

Comment: The numbers are radians, correct?

Comment: I looked into Taylor series, but with the absolute values it gets messy to the point that it doesn't seem productive.

Comment: @Jonny Yes, radians.

Comment: Maybe there's a suitable Riemann sum?  Note that
$$
|\cos(1)| + |\cos(2)| + |\cos(3)| = 
\int_0^1[3 \sin(3t) + 2 \sin(2t) - \sin(t)]dt - 1
$$

Comment: More shots in the dark: maybe near angle approximations will work?  For example,
$$
\cos(1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\cos(1-\pi/4) - \sin(1-\pi/4))
$$

Comment: FYI in case you're interested, this is a special case of a more general result: $|\cos(x-1)| + |\cos(x)| + |\cos(x+1)| \geq 3/2$ for all real $x$. There's a nice proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918877/prove-cosx%E2%88%921cosxcosx1%E2%89%A53-2

Comment: @Bungo I'm trying to follow the argument in the accepted answer on that page. I am getting that $\sqrt{a^2+1}$ is the *maximal* value of $a\sin x+\cos x$, contrary to what the poster claims (I have also confirmed this with Mathematica). Am I missing something here? (I don't have the rep to comment on that question yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the inequality $|\cos(x)| \ge |1-\frac{2}{\pi}x|$ for all $x \in [0, \pi]$.

Plugging in values, we obtain:

$$|\cos(1)|+|\cos(2)|+|\cos(3)| \ge \frac{8}{\pi}-1\ge \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: This cuts it surprisingly close! Well done!

Comment: Wow, this is really nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have:$$\begin{eqnarray*}|\cos 1|+|\cos 2|+|\cos 3|&=&\cos 1+\cos(\pi-2)+\cos(\pi-3)\\&=&\cos 1+2\cos\frac{1}{2}\cos\frac{2\pi-5}{2}\\&\geq&\cos 1+2\cos\frac{1}{2}\cos\frac{2}{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and since $\cos x\geq 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ for any $x\in[0,1]$ we have:
$$|\cos 1|+|\cos 2|+|\cos 3|\geq\frac{1}{2}+2\cdot \frac{7}{8}\cdot\frac{7}{9}>\frac{9}{5}.$$

Comment: $5/4$ is smaller than $3/2$. But fortunately this is because you dropped the $1/2$, so the final RHS should really be $7/4 > 3/2$.

Comment: @Bungo: there was a typo. $\frac{67}{36}>\frac{9}{5}>\frac{3}{2}.$